# setup a chained payment on paypal with php

Tags: php, paypal, chained-payments

I give up. I am trying to set up a chained payment on my site (done in php) and I am struggling a lot. Is there a good tutorial, example or could anyone advice me how to set up basics of paypal chained payment in php?
I need to set up headers and make a pay call and I can not achieve even that.

Thanks in advance

Ondrej

Comment: Struggling is not nice :( But what have you looked at so far and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) will make this very simple for you.  Take a look at it, read through the short documentation, and then take a look in the /samples folder.  It includes a chained payment sample.

Comment: IM-PRE-SIVE! My skills in php-basic/ Time needed to have this up and running-30min. You are a PHP God and belong to PHP Olympus. Well done.

Comment: One more question. With this new paypal developer site I am not sure I am using the right paypal credentials. It always returns an error 520003-API credentials are wrong. I am calling Pay() in Adaptive Payments and want to use sandbox credentials. Am I supposed to use the credentials given to the sandbox test account that is marked as a facilitator? If not, where do I get the right credentials? Does it matter that I am calling the paypal api from Slovakia IP?

Comment: I prefer to create a fresh account to use as a the seller account.  Then you can click on the Profile link for that account and it'll show you the API credentials. For adaptive payments you also need the App ID, which is included in the library for sandbox testing.  When you go live you'll have to submit your app for approval to get a live App ID.

Comment: Nope. I have made a new account, inserted the details, app ID is standard sandbox id which is already included in your library... and it returns failure:52003/ Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect. If I put them here: https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/AdaptivePayments It works fine. And vice-versa...If I use their details, it doesn't work on my site. I am using your code (pay from samples) and I changed only three lines that require api credentials. That leads me to impression that something must be wrong with my server, country code,eye colour or I don't know with what.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've got some sort of conflict with the $sandbox value.  Send me the file you're working with and I'll see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hello @AndrewAngell Steel this library working fine ?